# Why does my program skip over digits when printing out my letterList array? It is only printing out A-Z and a-z

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, bubble-sort

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
    numberList.add(1);
    numberList.add(5);
    numberList.add(3);
    numberList.add(4);
    ArrayList<String> letterList = new ArrayList<>();
    letterList.add("a");
    letterList.add("9");
    letterList.add("c");
    letterList.add("F");

    for (int x = 0; x < letterList.size(); x++) {
        String combo = letterList.get(x);
        String letter = combo.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
        letterList.set(x, letter);
    }
    bubbleSort(numberList, letterList);
}

public static void bubbleSort(ArrayList<Integer> numberList, ArrayList<String> letterList) {
    int n = numberList.size();
    int temp = 0;
    String temp2 = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {

            if (numberList.get(j - 1) > numberList.get(j)) {
                temp = numberList.get(j - 1);
                temp2 = letterList.get(j - 1);
                numberList.set(j - 1, numberList.get(j));
                letterList.set(j - 1, letterList.get(j));
                numberList.set(j, temp);
                letterList.set(j, temp2);
            }

        }
    }
    System.out.println(letterList);
}
```

It is supposed to sort the numberList and sort the letterList by going off of how it sorted the numberList

For example array {1,5,3,4} and array {a,9,c,F} It's supposed to sort the first one to {1,3,4,5} and the second one to {a,c,F,9}. However when I try to print out the letterList it skips over any numbers that are supposed to be in the array. Please see if you can help, sorry about the formatting I have no idea how to insert code.

Answer (score 1):

In this loop

```
for (int x = 0; x < letterList.size(); x++) {
    String combo = letterList.get(x);
    String letter = combo.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
    letterList.set(x, letter);
}
```

You replace any numbers in your letter list with empty strings.

If you don't want to do that, just remove that entire for loop.

Edit:

If you need to filter entries that are delimited by a space do it like this:

```
String myStr; //populate this value with your raw string
String[] mySplit = myStr.split(" "); //split it into an array around spaces
numberList.add(Integer.parse(mySplit[0]));
letterList.add(mySplit[1]);
```

Note this assumes that your inputs will always be formatted as you described, i.e. a number followed by a string separated by one white space.

Comment: If I'm reading from a file that has the format 1 A, 2 f, 32 3, 93 r, where the first part is some number, and the 2nd part after the " " is supposed to be a string, not an integer. How do I go about adding only the numbers to my numberList, but still adding the string after that, even if it is an integer, to my letterList?

Comment: There's a typo in `String mySplit`; should read `String[] mySplit`.

Comment: Thank you a lot @nhouser9. Really saved my ass haha.

Comment: @Copperhorse no problem - if my answer helped you i would appreciate an upvote / accept